# Different extraction pipeline for train and test

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pandas, feature-extraction, pipelines

I'm trying to create a production-ready ML model.
The problem is as follows:

Training data: Database A + Plus python aggregations.

Testing data: Database B + Plus python aggregations.

Both databases have different attributes and context-based aggregations. Overall, however the data fetched after transformations is in the same format.

Is it ideal to build two different extraction pipelines in this case? Or, is there a better solution for this problem.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to test on another database - why are there two?

Comment: Yes, one fetches realtime data while other doesn't.

Comment: But couldnt you do your entire training / testing on the not realtime?

Comment: I wouldn't ask if that was the case.

Comment: What is stopping you? It is rather common that production data is in a different format but to do training and testing on different databases is a bit unusual.

Comment: "Both databases have different attributes and context-based aggregations." <- that's where you have to do some work: (1) the number and type of the features must be strictly the same in the training and test set. (2) a different distribution in the test data may cause bad performance.